# Hide input and output entered value as text with ability to change the value by showing input

Tags: jquery

Could you please advice me a plugin or a solution on jquery.

I need to have an input field with email type. When entered it shows just like on image attached.

[image: change on click]

You can click on the change link and input will be shown again with this value.

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately i have not managed to find any solution yet thats why i am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you a plugin like [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) or implement a custom solution like the following:

**HTML**

```
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<div id="email">eugene@gmail.com</div>
<a href="#" id="changeEmail" data-target="email">change</a>
```

**JS**

```
// Switch to Input //
$('#changeEmail').bind('click', function(e){

    // Prevent Switch if Already Input //
    if ($(this).get(0).tagName != 'input') {
        var $target = $('#'+$(this).data('target')); // Get Target Element
        var val = $target.text(); // Get Current Target Value

        // Swap Elements //
        $target.replaceWith('<input id="email" type="text" value="'+val+'" />');

        // Hide Change //
        $('#changeEmail').hide();
    }
});

// Switch to Div //
$(document).delegate('#email', 'blur', function(){

    // Prevent Switch if Input is Empty //
    if ($(this).val() != ''){
        $(this).replaceWith('<div id="email">'+$(this).val()+'</div>');
        $('#changeEmail').show();
    } else {
        $('#changeEmail').hide();
    }
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/n9BkM/5/)**

I hope this helps!

Comment: It`s great! But could you please provide some changes to make the input availible by default? And then after entering some data save it as a target element? Many thanks! It works but how its better to hide change button until email is not entered?

Comment: Thanks again, but please could you say why .changeEmail is not hidden in my example? http://jsfiddle.net/n9BkM/7/

Comment: @RooticalV. You had the CSS for your changeEmail anchor to reference an ID while the element uses a class; I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n9BkM/8/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
`<span>Eugene@gmail.com</span><a href="#" onclick="var value = $(this).prev().text();$(this).prev().hide().after('<input type=text name=email value="'+value+'">')">Change</a>`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#changelink").click(function(){
   $("#emaildiv").text($("#inputarea").val())
})
```

Comment: I don't know you html so i'm making up elements